# ¿Porqué en C++ cuando pongo std::cin al principio, std::getline ya no es válido?

Tags: c++, string, poo

Soy nuevo en C++, y estoy aprendiendo a usar strings, y me encuentro con un pequeño problema, dentro del int main() una vez que pongo std::cin >> x; dentro,  std::getline(std::cin, x); ya no es válido
Escribiré específicamente el código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string s;

    std::cin >> s;

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Una cosa que he descubierto es que si pones 2 veces la misma linea de: std::getline(std::cin, s);
Si funciona, es decir, la primera no se hace válida, pero la segunda si, cualquier duda o algo que no dejé claro me lo pueden comentar por favor, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para entender lo que está pasando, una pequeña introducción:

- `std::cin` No devuelve el control hasta que no se ha introducido un salto de línea
- Los *streams* de entrada utilizan una lista de caracteres como separadores. Éstos sirven para delimitar números y cadenas de texto. Por defecto son los siguientes:

  - Salto de línea
  - Retorno de carro
  - Espacio
  - Tabulador

Así, cuando vas a rellenar el primer string, en el *stream* puedes encontrar algo tal que:

```
abcdefg\n
```

El operador de extracción es una función que opera de la siguiente manera:

- Intenta recuperar un string, por lo que si lo primero que encuentra son separadores, los descartará.
- Cuando encuentra un caracter que no es un separador empezará a rellenar el string.
- El proceso se detendrá cuando se encuentre con otro separador, **dejando el separador en el buffer de entrada**
- Este mecanismo se reproduce en las diferentes versiones del operador de extración **excepto** en la versión que extrae un `char`. Esta función en concreto devolverá siempre el primer caracter que haya en el *stream*, sea un separador o no.

La función `std::getline` funciona de forma algo diferente, ya que **no descarta** los separadores que haya al inicio de la secuencia. Esto es así para permitir que `getline` pueda leer líneas vacías.

Lo que sucede entonces es que `getline` se encuentra con que en el buffer de entrada hay un salto de línea, así que devuelve una línea vacía y la ejecución del programa continua.

Para evitar este inconveniente basta con descartar el salto de línea antes de hacer la llamada a `getline`

```
std::cin.ignore(); // Descarta un char del stream
```

Si quisieses forzar una limpieza completa del buffer entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Esta versión eliminará todo lo que haya en el buffer de entrada hasta el primer salto de línea que se encuentre, que también se descartará.